# Set a range and use that range in a formula

Tags: excel, vba, set, range

I am unable to figure out how to use a `set` range in a formula:

```
set range = Application.InputBox(prompt:="test", Title:="test", Type:=8)
Sheets("sheet1").Cells(3, 4).Formula = "=sum(range)"
```

All that is returned is `sum(range)`, not the actual sum of the selected cells.

I've tried `range.address` and a couple other variations to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is a string, so you need to concatenate your range address into your formula:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Cells(3, 4).Formula = "=sum(" & range.Address & ")"
```

You should probably use a different name for your variable, however, as `Range` is a built-in type/function in Excel VBA.

Comment: Just doubling down on the "...use a different name for your variable...".  I tend to use `rng` or `myRange` or something instead of `Range`.